# Changing font-size of <li> on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

I am adding some pages on a wordpress themed website. There is a table with 3 columns: 1st column will be the title (larger font).

Since it looks better and editing is easier, I started using `<ul>` instead of `<td>`

Even though it works fine on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pCc9w/124/) font-size on the 1st column does not change on wordpress website. I also tried using `<span>` instead of `<li>`, no luck.

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
    <td width="40%">
        <span class="span-test">SpTitle</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="li-test">LiTitle</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td width="30%">
        <ul>
            <li>Name 1</li>
            <li>Name 2</li>
            <li>Name 3</li>
            <li>Name 4</li>
            <li>Name 5</li>
            <li>Name 6</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td width="30%">
        <ul>
            <li>Spec 1</li>
            <li>Spec 2</li>
            <li>Spec 3</li>
            <li>Spec 4</li>
            <li>Spec 5</li>
            <li>Spec 6</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: may be some rule is overriding, you may use !important

Comment: can you provide your word press site link

Comment: !important didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have style inheritance from upper element, check it with dev. tools in browser.
You can also try to set inline style for:

```
<li style: "font-size: 22px;">Name 1</li>
```

or add !important in your css file, like this:

```
td > ul li
{
    font-size: 22px !important;">
}
```

Comment: 1st option didn't work but the second one did. Thank you Dima